# How to specify Maven Goals' Parameter value

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, jacoco

http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html

I am like really not familiar with maven at all. And the project that I am working on requires it....

I am trying to customize this Jacoco tool in maven. Especially the "include" parameter for prepare-agent goal. I am testing a big project with about 4000 classes in many different packages. But the only coverage information that I need is only from 5-10 classes.

Any idea how I can specify something like this? Basically specify "include" while running test. Or do I have to specify it in the POM file?

"mvn jacoco:prepare-agent -Dinclude = "weka.associations.Apriori" test"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can specify in the pom.xml file

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.4.201502262128</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*_.*</exclude>
                </excludes>
         </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
           </executions>
            </configuration>
</plugin
```

where exclude tag will include your exclusion list , the classes which you want yo exclude to get code coverage, right now , it will not exclude anything

Kindly use the new version of jacoco as it is old one which i have specified

Comment: <includes>
<include>src/weka.associations.*</include>
</includes>   something like this? It didn't work...

Comment: you can check the below link which contains all the info which you are looking for https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/creating-code-coverage-reports-for-unit-and-integration-tests-with-the-jacoco-maven-plugin/